# CSS - How to have 100% height element inside of parent

Tags: html, height, css

I have only made a 100% of the whole page, but this time I need a 100% height of element (div) inside of a parent.

I tried to re-read this for 100% height elements inside of parents, but nothing has worked so far.

http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html

HTML:

```
<div class="links content">
  <ul>
      <li>
        <h3> News </h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Adoption Stories</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Shelter News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Paw For Paw</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3> Resources </h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Breed Info</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dog Care</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3> Save a Paw </h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Adopt</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Volunteer</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- .links -->
```

CSS:

```
#main-content {
  background: #a8bfa5;
}

.links {
  background: #d4d7d8;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 190px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.links ul {
  padding: 5px;
}

.links ul li {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

`#main-content` is the parent of `.links`

example: want the gray box to reach top to bottom:

[image]

Comment: sorry if you don't understand this, wrote it quickly...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following trick:

```
#main-content {
   overflow: hidden;
}
.links {
   padding-bottom: 1000px;
   margin-bottom: -1000px;
}
```

Adjust the values for your own case.
Take a look at an example code http://jsfiddle.net/kXfsY/9/
Also here is one interesting technique explained in detail - http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use `float: left` on your div.links and put your "Paw for Paw" texts on another div (I'm assuming these texts should be on the right of your div.links when the div occupied the full height on the left? ). The `min-height: 100%` works fine in my testing. Besides, do you mind to let us know what browser are you using for the test? One more thing, since you are using padding on `div.links` and you wanted a `height: 100%` at the same time, I think you have to do some `margin offset` to get your desire result.

Answer (score -4):

Use a background-image or JavaScript.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: If you put a background image of a gray box in the green div, the gray will span the entire height.  If you use JavaScript, you can detect the height of the green box and resize the gray box to that exact pixel height.